# Error in reading JSON file

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2008

I need to parse/read this json file.

```html
   [{"children":[],"id":"dam/photo/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_i_oem_1","site":"dam","authorNames":["Volvo Cars of North America, Inc."],"captionTranscript":"2001 Volvo V70 XC AWD 4dr Wagon ","type":"PHOTOS","subType":"interior","shotTypeAbbreviation":"I","photoSrcs":["/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_i_oem_1_396.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_i_oem_1_196.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_i_oem_1_400.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_i_oem_1_300.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_i_oem_1_98.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_i_oem_1_87.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_i_oem_1_276.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_i_oem_1_500.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_i_oem_1_131.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_i_oem_1_185.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_i_oem_1_150.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_i_oem_1_175.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_i_oem_1_423.jpg"],"source":"OEM","vdpOrder":3},{"children":[],"id":"dam/photo/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_r_oem_1","site":"dam","authorNames":["Volvo Cars of North America, Inc."],"captionTranscript":"2001 Volvo V70 XC AWD 4dr Wagon ","type":"PHOTOS","subType":"exterior","shotTypeAbbreviation":"R","photoSrcs":["/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_r_oem_1_500.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_r_oem_1_423.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_r_oem_1_87.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_r_oem_1_400.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_r_oem_1_185.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_r_oem_1_98.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_r_oem_1_131.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_r_oem_1_196.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_r_oem_1_276.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_r_oem_1_396.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_r_oem_1_175.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_r_oem_1_150.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_r_oem_1_300.jpg"],"source":"OEM","vdpOrder":6},{"children":[],"id":"dam/photo/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_1","site":"dam","authorNames":["Volvo Cars of North America, Inc."],"captionTranscript":"2001 Volvo V70 XC AWD 4dr Wagon ","type":"PHOTOS","subType":"exterior","shotTypeAbbreviation":"RQ","photoSrcs":["/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_1_131.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_1_98.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_1_87.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_1_185.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_1_150.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_1_400.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_1_175.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_1_423.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_1_276.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_1_500.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_1_396.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_1_300.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_1_196.jpg"],"source":"OEM","vdpOrder":2},{"children":[],"id":"dam/photo/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_1","site":"dam","authorNames":["Volvo Cars of North America, Inc."],"captionTranscript":"2001 Volvo V70 XC AWD 4dr Wagon ","type":"PHOTOS","subType":"exterior","shotTypeAbbreviation":"FQ","photoSrcs":["/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_1_131.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_1_276.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_1_98.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_1_185.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_1_500.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_1_400.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_1_175.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_1_300.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_1_87.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_1_150.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_1_423.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_1_196.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_1_396.jpg"],"source":"OEM","vdpOrder":1},{"children":[],"id":"dam/photo/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_2","site":"dam","authorNames":["Volvo Cars of North America, Inc."],"captionTranscript":"2001 Volvo V70 XC AWD 4dr Wagon ","type":"PHOTOS","subType":"exterior","shotTypeAbbreviation":"RQ","photoSrcs":["/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_2_300.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_2_150.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_2_196.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_2_185.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_2_87.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_2_175.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_2_500.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_2_131.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_2_423.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_2_276.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_2_396.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_2_98.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_rq_oem_2_400.jpg"],"source":"OEM","vdpOrder":7},{"children":[],"id":"dam/photo/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_2","site":"dam","authorNames":["Volvo Cars of North America, Inc."],"captionTranscript":"2001 Volvo V70 XC AWD 4dr Wagon ","type":"PHOTOS","subType":"exterior","shotTypeAbbreviation":"FQ","photoSrcs":["/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_2_196.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_2_500.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_2_185.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_2_150.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_2_400.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_2_87.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_2_131.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_2_276.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_2_98.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_2_423.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_2_396.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_2_300.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_fq_oem_2_175.jpg"],"source":"OEM","vdpOrder":5},{"children":[],"id":"dam/photo/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_s_oem_1","site":"dam","authorNames":["Volvo Cars of North America, Inc."],"captionTranscript":"2001 Volvo V70 XC AWD 4dr Wagon ","type":"PHOTOS","subType":"exterior","shotTypeAbbreviation":"S","photoSrcs":["/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_s_oem_1_185.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_s_oem_1_400.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_s_oem_1_131.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_s_oem_1_196.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_s_oem_1_396.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_s_oem_1_87.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_s_oem_1_276.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_s_oem_1_300.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_s_oem_1_423.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_s_oem_1_175.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_s_oem_1_500.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_s_oem_1_150.jpg","/volvo/v70/2001/oem/2001_volvo_v70_wagon_xc_s_oem_1_98.jpg"],"source":"OEM","vdpOrder":4}]
```

Here is the class code that I am using to deserialize it using the JSON.net

```html
 public class Photo
    {

        public List<Children> children;

    }
    public class Children
    {
        public string id;
        public string site;
        public List<string> authorNames;
        public string captionTranscript;
        public string type;
        public string subType;
        public string shotTypeAbbreviation;
        public List<string> photoSrcs;
        public string source;
        public string vdpOrder;
    }

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_filename);
    string str = sr.ReadToEnd();

    sr.Close();

    Photo p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Photo>(str);// this line gives error
```

But I am getting errors

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Photo' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: Please show the errors you're getting.

Comment: And I see no code, only two classes.

Comment: Code + Error Updated

Comment: It's not valid json. cut/pasting it into jsonlint shows an error at `Volvo [errorhere] Cars of North America`, probably because there's a linebreak there.

Comment: It was a bit long file , So i tried to Cut it .Now Original One is there ,checked with jsonlint validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is an array/list. So deserialize to a list.

```
var photos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Photo>>(json);
```

---

```
public class Photo
{
    public List<object> children { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string site { get; set; }
    public List<string> authorNames { get; set; }
    public string captionTranscript { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string subType { get; set; }
    public string shotTypeAbbreviation { get; set; }
    public List<string> photoSrcs { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public int vdpOrder { get; set; }
}
```